# sql select count query error to get number of table records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm just trying to get the count of records in a certain table within my data base , my code:

```
<?php
require_once("/../includes/connectDB.php");

$q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM  system_users";
    $result = mysql_query($q);
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
    $count = $result['Count'];
?>
```

i'm just getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$count' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sik\sections\Statistics.php on line 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script have the semicolon problem on line 6

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
```

change

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

you missed semicolon in line 6 but it showing error in line 7. why? becouse

Every PHP statement ends with a semicolon (;). PHP doesn't stop reading a statement until it reaches a semicolon. If you leave out the semicolon at the end of a line, PHP continues reading the statement on the following line. For example, consider the following statement:

```
$test = 1
echo $test;
```

These statements don't make sense to PHP; it reads the two lines as one statement, so it complains with an error message, such as the following:

Parse error: parse error in c:\test.php on line 2

Answer (score 2):

You are missing semicolon `;`

```
<?php
require_once("/../includes/connectDB.php");

$q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM  system_users";
    $result = mysql_query($q);
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                                      ^^^^^
    $count = $result['Count'];
?>
```